# A state legislator wishes to survey residents of her district to see what proportion p of the electorate..

Tags: statistics

A state legislator wishes to survey residents of her district to see what proportion $p$ of the electorate is aware of her position on using state funds to pay for abortions.

a) What sample size is necessary if the 95% CI (Confidence Interval) for $p$ is to have a width of at most .10 irrespective of $p$

b) If the legislator has strong reason to believe that at least $2/3$ of the electorate know of her position, how large a sample size would you recommend?

Comment: Are we given the number of citizens?

Comment: What does the $#$ of citizens have to do with anything pertaining to this question?

Comment: The answer you accepted was expressed as a number of needed people.  Would the answer have been the same if the population was, say, 10 people?  or 10^7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The largest confidence interval occurs when p = .5; the standard error is then $\sqrt\frac{.5^2}{x}$. Setting up an equation (for a z-test, the z* for a 95 percent confidence interval is 1.96), $1.96\sqrt\frac{.5^2}{x}=.05$. Solving gives $x=384.2$. So you need 385 people.

b) In that case, calculate the standard error using $2/3$ instead of $1/2$. Do $1.96\sqrt\frac{(2/3)(1/3)}{x}=.05$. Solving gives $x=341.48$. So you need 342 people.